# Page with fixed elements and filled with others?

Tags: javascript, css, html, fixed

I'd like to build a page with some fixed centered elements surrounded by elements thats fill all the space available (depending on browser's width).

Here's a wireframe to illustrate it : http://s23.postimg.org/pm61hyam3/Sans_titre_6.jpg

CSS3, JS ... Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Perhaps this library could help: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 0):

### Solution #1

I think the future way how to tackle this problem will be with [CSS Exclusions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-exclusions/).

### Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/t7Na4/1/) in IE10+

> CSS Exclusions extend the notion of content wrapping previously
>   limited to floats. ... Elements layout their inline content in their content area and wrap around the exclusion areas in their associated wrapping context (--excerpts from [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-exclusions/))

This [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh673558.aspx) also explains exclusions

> ...web authors can now wrap text so that it completely surrounds
>   elements, thereby avoiding the traditional limitations of floats.
>   Instead of limiting elements to floating either to the left or right
>   relative to their position in the document flow, CSS Exclusions can be
>   positioned at a specified distance from the top, bottom, left, or
>   right sides of a containing block, while remaining part of the
>   document flow.

Ironically, to date this only works in IE10 (look for wrap-flow:both [here](http://adobe.github.io/web-platform/utilities/css-exclusions-support-matrix/))

This is what the code looks like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="exclusion1"></div>
    <div class="exclusion2"></div>
    <div class="dummy_text">
       text here
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.exclusion1,  .exclusion2
{
    -ms-wrap-flow: both;
    -ms-wrap-margin: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.exclusion1
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: yellow;
}
.exclusion2
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    margin-top: 320px;
}
```

### Solution #2

The CSS-tricks article [Faking ‘float: center’ with Pseudo Elements](http://css-tricks.com/float-center/) should help.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/H7RQf/)**

### Markup

```
<div id="page-wrap">    
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/250" id="logo">

    <div id="l">
        <p>left column text</p>
    </div>

    <div id="r">
        <p>right column text</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

### CSS

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -125px;
}
#l, #r {
    width: 49%;
}
#l:before, #r:before {
    content: "";
    width: 125px;
    height: 250px;
}
#l {
    float: left;
}
#l:before {
    float: right;
}

#r {
    float: right;
}
#r:before {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: CSS exclusions is the perfect solution, too bad that only IE10 support this for now ... The second solution is a good trick, but is it possible to add text also on top of the picture (and not juste left-rigth and bottom) ?